# How to change Hugo-Coder avatar based on if dark mode is enabled?

Tags: html, css, markdown, hugo, toml

#### Background of environment

- I am currently building a site in Hugo using the theme `Hugo-Coder`
- `avatar.png` is my current avatar specified in `config.toml`

---

#### Summary of issue

- In `config.toml` you can enable dark mode by adding: `colorscheme = "auto"`
- This enables dark mode, but my avatar does not show well because it is black

---

#### Solution needed

- I need a way to change `avatar.png` to `avatarDarkMode.png` based on if the user's system is set to light or dark mode

---

Hopefully I added enough information!

Source code repo: [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/nickkjolsing/website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider a shortcode similar to the one used in [`onweru/newsroom`](https://github.com/onweru/newsroom/blob/23d496eb879c1610fc6530cbb50beb1e5b8eb0e4/README.md#custom-shortcodes):

> Picture You want to use darkmode images when darkmode is enabled on a device and a regular image on lightmode? It takes 3 positional parameter
>
> Store these images in the `static/images` directory.
>
> ```
> ...
> {{< picture "lightModeImage.png" "darkModeImage.png" "Image alt text" >}}
> ...
> ```

It uses [`layouts/shortcodes/picture.html`](https://github.com/onweru/newsroom/blob/057d966c8d5d4c52c81b0f4fceca6c1347e610e6/layouts/shortcodes/picture.html):

```html
{{- $normal := .Get 0 }}
{{- $dark := .Get 1 }}
{{- $alt := .Get 2 }}
{{- $normalPath := absURL (printf "images/%s" $normal) }}
{{- $darkPath := absURL (printf "images/%s" $dark) }}
<picture class = 'nav_logo'>
  <source srcset = '{{ $darkPath }}' media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
  <img srcset = '{{ $normalPath }}' alt = '{{ $alt }}'>
</picture>
```

---

> How about SVG file?
> Is there any way to change the style of an SVG file instead of creating two different SVG image, one for dark mode and one for light mode?

For SVG, you can try **CSS Media Queries**:
You can use CSS media queries to detect whether the user has a light or dark theme enabled in their operating system or browser, and then apply different styles to the SVG accordingly.
For example:

```css
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
   svg {
       filter: invert(1);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you so much! Hadn't been aware of how shortcode could be used until now.

Comment: @melondoor Great! Well done. Shortcuts are quite useful indeed.

Comment: @VonC, how about SVG file? Is there any way to change the style of a SVG file instead of creating two different SVG image, one for dark mode and one for light mode. Thanks for any information.

Comment: @VonC, how to response to dark and light schemes by click as provided by a theme. I am using Coder theme. I have tried `prefers-color-scheme: light` but it does not work. Thank you for any information.

Comment: @VonC I post the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76554969/9475509) even I do not really understand how it works. Please correct it if it is not safe. Thank you.