# Toggle dark / light mode in Hugo theme Coder to affect SVG image and Mermaid diagram

Tags: css, svg, darkmode, mermaid

I use Hugo theme [Coder](https://github.com/luizdepra/hugo-coder), which has option `hideColorSchemeToggle` in the `hugo.toml` file, which makes it very convenient to toggle between dark and light mode by only clicking the icon.

I want that SVG image and [Mermaid](https://mermaid.js.org/) diagram also change as the mode is changed. Then, after reading and asking around, I try to copy the file `_content_dark.scss` located in the folder `themes\hugo-coder\assets\scss` to folder `assets\scss` and modify it.

Near end of the file, the original content is as follow

```scss
body.colorscheme-dark {
  @include content_dark();
}
```

which is later changed to

```scss
body.colorscheme-dark {
  @include content_dark();
  svg {
    filter: invert(1);
  }
  .mermaid {
    filter: invert(0);
  }
}
```

And it does work. I can have SVG image and Mermaid diagram to change as I toggle between dark and light mode.

The question is, whether this way safe? Or is there any better way to achieve this? And what if I want to have different color variations beside supported by `filter: invert(n)`? I am just worry that the results are only coincidence and will be different in other theme, since I do not really understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying the `_content_dark.scss` file as described can be considered "relatively safe" in the sense that it uses standard CSS to adjust the styles based on the theme.

However,if you modify files within the theme itself, these changes could be overwritten if you update the theme in the future. To avoid this, it is recommended to create a custom CSS file and include it in your site instead of modifying the theme's files directly.

That means creating a new CSS file where you can place your custom styles. This file should be located within the `assets` directory of your Hugo site. For example, create a file named `custom.css` within the `assets/css` directory (you might need to create the `css` directory if it does not exist).

Edit the `custom.css` file and add the custom styles you want to apply to your site. For example, you can add custom styles for dark mode:

```css
body.colorscheme-dark svg {
    filter: invert(1);
}
```

You then need to tell Hugo to use your custom CSS file: edit the HTML template files that Hugo uses to generate your site. One way to do this is to create a file called `head.html` in the `layouts/partials` directory of your site (create the directories if they do not exist).

Within `head.html`, add the following code to link your custom CSS file:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "css/custom.css" | absURL }}">
```

In the main layout file, which is usually located in `layouts/_default/baseof.html`, you need to include the `head.html` partial you just created. Find the `<head>` section of your `baseof.html` file and include your partial by adding the following code inside the `<head>` tags:

```html
{{ partial "head.html" . }}
```

finally, run `hugo server` from the command line to build your site and start the development server. Visit your site in a web browser to make sure that your custom styles are being applied correctly.

This way, you are not modifying the theme's files directly, and your custom styles are kept separate. This makes it less likely that your changes will be accidentally overwritten if you update the theme, and it also makes it easier to manage your customizations.

---

Additionally, the `filter: invert(1)` method is a bit of a "blunt instrument". It inverts *all* the colors, which might not always give you the results you want. If you want more control over the specific colors used in dark mode, you might want to use a different approach.

For more control over color variations, you might consider using [CSS Custom Properties (variables)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) or more targeted CSS rules. Here is an example using CSS Custom Properties:

```scss
body.colorscheme-dark {
  --primary-color: #your-dark-mode-color;
  --secondary-color: #another-dark-mode-color;
  // ... more custom properties
}

svg {
  fill: var(--primary-color);
}
```

This example sets custom properties for the primary and secondary colors in dark mode, and then uses those properties to set the fill color of the SVG elements. This gives you more fine-grained control over the colors used in dark mode, rather than just inverting them.

Comment: I will let you know, after I try it. Thank you. By they way the Coder theme already has its own 'head.html', I should modify it by adding the lines you suggested, right?

Comment: @dudung The all idea is to *not* modify the theme. Copy the `head.html` from the theme's directory (likely located in `themes/coder/layouts/partials`) to your site's `layouts/partials` directory. Modify it there. By copying and modifying the `head.html` file in your own `layouts/partials` directory, you are making use of Hugo's lookup order, which prioritizes files in your site's `layouts` directory over those in the theme's directory. This means that your modified `head.html` will be used instead of the theme's original file, without you having to modify the theme itself.